# JavaScript template: wrap each word in a string in an HTML element

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to modify a JavaScript template such that each of the words in a particular string are wrapped in `<span>` elements. I have:

```
<% var tagString = "Happy Sad Up Down", tags = tagString.split(" "), wrappedTags = ""; %>
<% for (var i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) { %>
    <% wrappedTags += "<span>" + tags[i] + "</span>"; %>
<% } %>
<p><%=wrappedTags%></p>
```

The problem is that this outputs the `"<span>"` and `"</span>"` as text, not HTML, so I end up with the following text being displayed on the page:

<span>Happy</span><span>Sad</span><span>Up</span><span>Down</span>

Is there any way within this syntax to output the wrapping `<span>` tags as HTML?

---

UPDATE: with regular (non-template) syntax, it works if I simply write `wrappedTags` to the page: http://jsfiddle.net/4QtUd/. However, I can't figure out the equivalent way to do this within the template syntax.

Comment: What template framework are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this, outputting it directly within the loop.

```
<% var tagString = "Happy Sad Up Down", tags = tagString.split(" "); %>
<p>
<% for (var i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) { %>
    <span><%= tags[i] %></span>
<% } %>
</p>
```

Comment: Perfect! That's so obvious now, haha.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your `<` and `>`with HTML entities.
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp

So basically: `< -> &lt;` and `> -> &gt;`

Comment: That still outputs as text, so I get "&lt;span&gt;Happy&lt;/span&gt;", etc.